# Setting reminders in friends shared Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar, reminder

If I share a Google calendar with a friend and add events to it, is there some way that I can set reminders for those events in his instance of that calendar?

Comment: I think this question's terminology is wrong, really asking about notifications. Reminders are now a formal thing in Google Calendar to mean a task that should be completed and checked off.

Answer (score 3):

Google Calendar does *not* automatically send reminders for events.  Only when a reminder has been set will a reminder be prompted.

You can't set a reminder for individual users; you can only set reminders for the event which will prompt anybody who has access to a shared calendar.

To set a reminder:

1. Click on the event.
2. Click on *Edit event*.
3. Go to **Reminders** and click *Add reminder*.
4. If the default options aren't suitable (managed in your calendar settings) select your preferred reminder type from the drop-down box and enter the time and minutes/hours/days, etc. option from the second drop-down box.
5. Save your event.

Answer (score 0):

Google calendar automatically sends emails reminding you and the other involved people about the event, It reminds you some time before and then 5 or 10 minutes before the event.
But if you double click on the event where you write all the event specifications and add your friends emails there is a part that says reminders there you can program when you want the reminders to be sent.

Comment: This seems partially correct. By default I get event notifications 10 minutes before, but inviting guests to a calendar event and then creating a notification doesn't notify them.

Comment: @CarlWalsh did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a change to your friend's notification settings. (Well, unless you get access to their device signed in as them and make the change below...)

What your friend **can** do is use their account and go into the settings for that calendar, then add one more more default notifications. This change seems to apply to existing events too!

If you need to set different notifications for some events, it's not pretty but you could create multiple shared calendars like SharedCalendard10Mins, SharedCalendard1Hour, SharedCalendardNoNotification?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Google Calendar.
2. Under “My Calendars,” check Reminders.
3. In the top left, click Create Create event.
4. In the pop-up box, click Reminder.
5. Type your reminder or choose a suggestion.
6. Choose a date, time, and frequency.
7. Click Save.